# How to fix NameError for a method in a class?

Tags: python-3.x, traceback

I'm making a class that does simple statistical calculations. However, I'm getting a `NameError` when I run the code. The line
*"This program computes mean, median, standard deviation, minimum, and maximum."* prints, but afterwards crashes with the error.

Code:

```
from math import sqrt

class StatSet:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def addNumber(self, x):
        if x in self.data:
             self.data[x] += 1
         else:
             self.data[x] = 1

    def mean(self):
        total = sum(num*count for num,count in self.data.items())
        return total / self.count()

    def median(self):
        midway = (self.count() + 1) // 2
        countingUp = 0
        for num in sorted(list(self.data)):
            countingUp += self.data[num]
            if countingUp >= midway:
                return num

    def stdDev(self):
        num = sum([(num - self.mean())**2*count for num, count in
        self.data.items()])
        den = self.count() -1
        return sqrt(num/den)

    def count(self):
        return sum(self.data.values())

    def min(self):
       return min(self.data)

    def max(self):
       return max(self.data)

    def getNumbers():
        nums = StatSet()
        xStr = input("Enter a number (<Enter> to quit) >> ")
        while xStr != "":
            x = eval(xStr)
            nums.addNumber(x)
            xStr = input("Enter a number (<Enter> to quit) >> ")
            return nums

    def main():
        print("This program computes mean, median, standard "
              "deviation, minimum, and maximum. \n")

        data = getNumbers()
        xbar = data.mean()
        std = data.stdDev()
        med = data.median()
        minNum = data.min()
        maxNum = data.max()

        print("\nThe mean is", xbar)
        print("The standard deviation is", std)
        print("The median is", med)
        print("The minimum value is", minNum)
        print("The maximum value is", maxNum)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python Files\statset.py", line 3, in <module>
    class StatSet:
  File "C:\Python Files\statset.py", line 68, in StatSet
    main()
  File "C:\Python Files\statset.py", line 54, in main
    data = getNumbers()
NameError: name 'getNumbers' is not defined
```

Comment: Include the full stack trace (error) as formatted text into the question and make sure to properly indent your code. The stack trace should tell you exactly which function and which line that generates the error.

Comment: How would I insert it as formatted text?

Comment: Copy the stack trace and edit it in as a code block. This is done just as your code, by surrounding it with \`\`\` at the beginning and end, or by indenting everything by one step.

Comment: Did it. Thank you.

Comment: The code you provided has weird indentations, and these are crucial to determine scope. I am guessing your function `getNumbers()` is defined within the scope of your class (as opposed to globally), so your `main()` function would not see it. If this is indeed the case, you will need to call it on an instance of the class (for example, `ss = StatSet()` and then `ss.getNumbers()`).

Comment: I added `ss = StatSet()` and `ss.getNumbers()` to `main()` , ran the code, and now I'm getting `NameError: name 'StatSet' is not defined`.

Comment: You need to fix your indention so that it properly reflects your actual code, otherwise we can only guess what your problem is. Is `getNumbers` a method in the class or a free-standing function?

Comment: Ok, it now looks like my actual code. I'm new to python so it is possible that I messed up the indentation quite a bit.

Comment: Is `main` suppose to be inside the class also?

Comment: Yes because I will be using this class with another program.

Comment: Firstly, `else` at line 11 is producing an `IndentionError`. Make sure that the code you post is producing the error you're expecting. Secondly, it doesn't really make sense for `main` and the `if`-statement to both be inside the class. Also, all methods inside a class should have a `self` parameter, which `getNumbers` doesn't have. It looks like you meant for it to be a free-standing function (i.e. **outside** of the class).